Angular 17 not update a child component using the same function called for diferents functions?
Im using a child component to show a single message in a div:
<tmpl-breadcrumb [title]="title" [subtitle]="subtitle"></tmpl-breadcrumb>
I use the follow function to change the subtitle:
  setSubTitle(subtitle1: string) {
    this.subtitle = subtitle1;
  }


When call that function from the follow function works ok:
getAlerts() {
    this.loading = true;
    this._alertService.getAlerts(this.filters).subscribe(
      (item) => {
        this.loading = false;
        if (item.success) {
          this.alerts = item.data;

          this.setSubTitle(
            `Last update at ${moment(item.lastUpdate).format('lll')}`
          );
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

The problem is when i call the same function from a observable:
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAlerts();
    this._updateService
      .listenChannel('events', '.updates')
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        
        this.setSubTitle(data);
      });
  }

The console.log show the data correctly, but the tmpl-breadcrumb component not show the change.
Here is my tmpl-breadcrumb:
import { Component, Input, SimpleChange } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector:'tmpl-breadcrumb',
    standalone: true,
    templateUrl: '../views/tmpl-breadcrumb.component.html'
})

export class TmplBreadcrumbComponent{
    @Input() title = ''
    @Input() subtitle = ''

    ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChange){
       console.log(this.subtitle);
    }
}


and the html:
<div class="page-titles">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><h5 class="bc-title">{{ title }}</h5></li>
    </ol>
    {{ subtitle }}
</div>

Why the getAlerts function change the subtitle all the time when i call and the subscribe not??
Im expect change the title of my template.
"Last update at Apr 4, 2024 8:18 PM"
